# How to remove the need of "./" in every shell script in MacOS?

Tags: shell, sh, zsh

I'm studying shellscript and I know that there is a way to skip "./" when you need to execute a shellscript.
For example: after I made a script like this:

```
echo "hello world!"
```

I use the command "chmod +X" to make it executable. But to execute it on my terminal I need to type:

```
./helloworld.sh
```

I know that theres is a way to skip this "./" if you're using bash. You go to .bashrc and write in the end of the script "PATH=PATH:."
But since I'm using MacOS, which use zsh, I tried to type "PATH=PATH:." in the end of my .zshrc but this didn't work.
Then I would like to know if there is a way to remove the need of "./" for every shellscript that I need to run.

Thank you people

P.S.: I have brew and ohmyzsh installed in my machine

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`. As an aside, I would suggest you don't do this as it might make the scripts you write less portable.

Comment: Note that there is a valid reason why the `./` prefix is typically required:  back before it was required, tricksy people would do things like creating a script named `ls` in some directory (with execute-permission set) and wait for some unsuspecting victim to cd to that directory and then type `ls`, at which point instead of getting a printout of the directory's contents, the script would run, and delete all his files (or whatever).

Comment: Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come

Comment: `PATH=PATH:.` is wrong even in bash. (And heed the advice above: Putting the CWD in the PATH is a bad idea; better to create a `~/bin` directory and keep all your scripts there; it's not just more secure, it's also more convenient because what you can run doesn't depend on which directory you're in).

Comment: Also, typosquatting on UNIX commands is a thing. Even if you've made sure real commands come first, that doesn't stop an attacker from filling `/tmp` with hostile typo'd versions of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What's Wrong with Your Code

The reason your example doesn't work is because *PATH* is a variable, and you need to expand it by prefixing it with the dollar sign to access its value, e.g. `PATH=$PATH:.` rather than just `PATH=PATH:.`. However, there are some other considerations too.

### Prepending, Appending, and Exporting *PATH*

It's generally not recommended to treat your current working directory as part of your *PATH* for security reasons, but you can do it in any Bourne-like shell by prepending or appending `.` (which means any current working directory) to your *PATH*. Depending on where you call it and how you've initialized your shell, you may also need to export the *PATH* variable to your environment.

Some examples include:

```
# find the named executable in the current working directory first
export PATH=".:$PATH"

# find the named executable in the current working directory
# only if it isn't found elsewhere in your PATH
export PATH="$PATH:."

# append only the working directory you're currently in when you
# update the PATH variable, rather than *any* current working 
# directory, to your PATH
export PATH="$PATH:$PWD"
```

Note that it's also generally a good idea to quote your variables, since spaces or other characters may cause problems when unquoted. For example, `PATH=/tmp/foo bar:$PATH` will either not work at all or not work as expected. So, wrap it up for safety (with quotes)!

### Use Direnv for Project-Based *PATH* Changes

You might also consider using a utility like [direnv](https://direnv.net/) that would enable you to add the current working directory to your *PATH* when you enter known-safe directories, and remove it from the *PATH* when leaving the directory. This is commonly used for development projects, including shell scripting ones.

For example, you could create the following `~/dev/foo/.envrc` file that would only prepend the current working directory when in `~/dev/foo`, and remove it again when you move above the current `.envrc` in your filesystem:

```
# ~/dev/foo/.envrc
#
# prepend "$HOME/dev/foo:$HOME/dev/foo/bin" to your 
# existing PATH when entering your project directory,
# and remove it from your PATH when you exit from the
# project

PATH_add "$PWD/bin"
PATH_add "$PWD"
```

Because direnv uses whitelisting and ensures that your items are prepended to *PATH*, it's often a safer and less error-prone way to manage project-specific modifications to your *PATH* or other environment variables.

### Use "$HOME/bin" to Consolidate Scripts

Another option is to create a directory for shell scripts in your home directory, and add that to your *PATH*. Then, any script placed there will be accessible from anywhere on your filesystem. For example:

```
# add this line to .profile, .zprofile, .zshrc, or
# whatever login script your particular terminal calls;
# on macOS, this should usually be .zprofile, but YMMV
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"

# make a ~/bin directory and place your
# executables there
mkdir -p ~/bin
cp helloworld.sh ~/bin/
```

Assuming the shell scripts in your bin directory already have their executable bit set (e.g. `chmod 755 ~/bin/*sh`), you can run any shell script in that directory from anywhere on your filesystem.

Comment: Quick note that the `export`s are unnecessary; changes to a variable that's already in the environment go directly back to the environment.

Comment: Also, leaving them out makes the quotes unambiguously unnecessary, since regular shell assignments suppress string splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your frequent bike-shedding gets very tiresome. There are some edge cases where *PATH* is not already exported (I could contrive an example, but you'd just argue about it) and I guarantee that an unquoted `PATH=$PATH:/tmp/foo bar` will result in `zsh: command not found: bar` even if the directory exists, and that `PATH=/tmp/foo bar:$PATH` can cause `zsh: command too long`. I stand by my answer as safer and more broadly applicable than your comments suggest, and invite you to write your own answer if you have one that's safer and more universal.

Comment: The example you gave in the comment above is a space present at lexing; I specifically referred only to string splitting (the parameter expansion step), thus to spaces already in the PATH or other variables being expanded. But yes, I'm just kibitzing here; there's nothing seriously wrong with this answer (if there has been, a downvote rather than an upvote would have accompanied my comment).

Answer (score 1):

You need `PATH=$PATH:.` -- the `$` to expand the (old) value of `PATH` is important.